# Proving Lagrange four square theorem from the "sum of three triangle" theorem

Tags: combinatorics, polygons, additive-combinatorics

It was proven by Gauss that every integer is the sum of at most three triangle numbers, and by Lagrange that every integer is the sum of at most four squares.

The triangles  are the set $\big\{1,3,6,10,\ldots\big\}$, and it's easy to see that the squares can be written as $\big\{1,1\!+\!3,3\!+\!6,6\!+\!10,\ldots\big\}$.
I wonder if it's generally the case that if a set $S$ (with $s_n$ the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ element) is a $p$-additive base for the integers, then the set $S^*=\big\{s_1,s_1+s_2,s_2+s_3,\ldots\big\}$ is (at most?) $p+1$ additive.

Comment: $\{0,1,3,5,7,9,\dots\}$ is a basis of order two, but $\{0,1,4,8,12,16,\dots\}$ is not a basis of order three.

Comment: Then probably it'll be a base of order  at most 2p, but that's quite unimpressive of course. Thanks